# Are these polynomial expressions valid or invalid?

Tags: polynomials

I am developing a program that recursively evaluates or defines polynomial expressions. However beyond basic polynomials I don't know where the line is drawn of what a valid polynomial is. For example:

Is

> 2x^(2x^(2x))

or

> 2x^(2x * 3x * (2x^3) )

or

> 2x^(2x /(2x^2))

Valid Polynomials?

I cannot find online on what constitutes as a valid polynomial when going deep into complex examples. I know the basics but on harder examples don't know.

Comment: Those are not polynoms.the exponents must not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial):

> In mathematics, a polynomial is an expression consisting of variables and coefficients which only employs the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and non-negative integer exponents. An example of a polynomial of a single variable $x$ is $x^2 − 4x + 7$. An example in three variables is $x^3 + 2xyz^2 − yz + 1$.

Something like $x^x$ cannot be written as the sum of non-negative integer powers of $x$ multiplied by coefficients, so it is not a polynomial. This should help.